# Erro de Timezone ao importar dump do Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Meu servidor de banco de dados pifou e preciso restaurar um dump de um banco de dados. Porém quando tento rodar a ferramenta imp do Oracle 10g xe ele me retorna o erro

```
1882 - região de fuso horário  não encontrada
```

Segue o log da ferramenta imp

> Import: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Qua Jul 1 18:57:32 2015
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> Conectado a: Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 -
>   Production
>
> Arquivo de exportação criado por EXPORT:V10.02.01 via caminho direto
>
> importação realizada nos conjuntos de caracteres WE8MSWIN1252 e NCHAR
>   AL16UTF16 o cliente de exportação usa o conjunto de caracteres
>   US7ASCII (conversão de charset possível)
>
> IMP-00058: Erro Oracle: 1882 encontrado ORA-01882: região de fuso
>   horário  não encontrada ORA-06512: em "SYS.DBMS_EXPORT_EXTENSION",
>   line 765 ORA-06512: em line 1 IMP-00009: fim anormal do arquivo de
>   exportação IMP-00000: Importação encerrada com êxito

O comando executado foi:

```
imp  file=C:\dumps\2015-06-27_biblioteca.dmp fromuser=BIBLIOTECA touser=BIBLIOTECA  buffer=1000000 commit=y Destroy=y ignore=y show=y skip_unusable_indexes=y
```

Obrigado a todos

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma [thread na comunidade do Oracle](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2198497) sobre esse problema.

Depois de lê-la, eu tentaria setar o seguinte em seu `AddVMOption -Duser.timezone=CET`:

```
AddVMOption -Duser.timezone=CET
```

Ou então algum timezone de seu local.

Pelo que entendi, isso seta o timezone da sua JVM.

Também não sei as consequências disso, mas preferencialmente tente usar o mesmo timezone antes configurado. Se funcionar, vale a pena verificar se funcionou a data certinho mesmo, no geral.

Comment: o problema é que essa thread diz respeito ao enterprise manager, não à ferramenta imp.

Comment: Pela documentação do imp, não achei nenhum parâmetro para setar o timezone. Talvez na hora de salvar o dump tenha alguma opção para incluí-lo no arquivo?

Comment: O problema que estou realizando um reatore de emergebcia